# How to filter by multiple criteria in Flask SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database shown below which works fine. Now I have a user called Bob that owns the space Mainspace. I would like to get a boolean to see if he is a owner of the space. I tried to apply two filters but I get the following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; use contains() to test for membership.
```

Command:

```
exists = Space.query.filter_by(name="Mainspace", owner="Bob").first()
```

Database:

```
space_access = db.Table('space_access',
    db.Column('userid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('spaceid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('space.id')))

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    role='admin';

    spaces = db.relationship('Space', secondary=space_access, backref=db.backref('owner', lazy='dynamic'))

class Space(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
```

Comment: filter_by(<whatever criteria>).first(). First() returns either a match or None. Since the match would be non-zero, it could be treated like a boolean.

Comment: I can't add to filter critearias. See my edited post above please.

Comment: filter_by() can include multiple criteria: filter_by(name='mainspace', owner='Bob').first(). Flask uses SQLAlchemy quite heavily. I would recommend you pause and read the SQLAlchemy docs and/or search online for some tutorials. It will benefit you greatly

Comment: I also tried that. Didn't work. I think I have to join something or my backref is pointing to the wrong table.

Comment: Is it possible your query was correct, but that you were missing the class name in query? From [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by), `session.query(MyClass).filter_by(name = 'some name')`. The docs include the case of multiple criteria filtering.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
existing = User.query.join(User.spaces).filter(User.username=='Bob', Space.name=='Mainspace').first()
print(existing.id)
if existing != None:
  print('Exists')
```